# ORACLE trigger issue - inserted multiple rows instead of one

Tags: oracle, triggers, database-trigger

I have an After Insert trigger on table A, Which is supposed to this -
1) After a row is inserted into table A, check some data of new row.
2) If the conditions are met, it will insert those data into another table B.
3) for one row inserted into table A, if conditions are met, only one row will be inserted into table B.

This trigger was working as design without any issues. Suddenly, couple of days ago, we noticed that for some rows inserted (not ALL) in table A, this trigger inserted multiple rows in table B. There are no apparent matching pattern in the rows, for which multiple rows in table B was inserted. There are no patterns in number of multiple rows either. I mean, for some rows in table A, 19/20/21 rows and some rows 27/28/30 rows were inserted into table B.

This problem happened for 2 days. And then this problem just disappeared. 
Now, I understand this is not an usual ORACLE issue. My question is, have any of experienced anything like this? if so, what could be the reason for this abnormal behavior?

Comment: Any chance there are autonomous transactions involved anywhere?  Otherwise, without seeing code, it's pretty difficult to guess.  I would tend to suspect that there is/was a bug in the trigger or that your application was doing something that the trigger wasn't expecting (i.e. deleting and inserting a row in A rather than updating it).

Comment: Is it an After Each Row or After Statement trigger?

Comment: What is the reference relation between A and B ? How you realize that all rows in B inserted together from a single trigger call?